# Rails - class String - Where does that go in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying the following tutorial: http://henrik.nyh.se/2007/03/ruby-wordwrap-method

It has a block that needs to be added somewhere I think outside of the helper:

```
class String
  # Replace the second of three capture groups with the given block.
  def midsub(regexp, &block)
    self.gsub(regexp) { $1 + yield($2) + $3 }
  end
end
```

Where should that be located in the rails 3 app? Thanks

**UPDATE**

**Added /lib/midsub.rb**

```
# Needed for html_format try 3
class String
  # Replace the second of three capture groups with the given block.
  def midsub(regexp, &block)
    self.gsub(regexp) { $1 + yield($2) + $3 }
  end
end
```

> application.rb
>
> ```
> config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
> ```

Comment: did you put it in the /lib or /initializers?  I see both here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add that code inside a file, let's say 'my_string.rb' in the /config/initializers folder

Comment: initializers or lib? the other answers suggest lib.

Comment: the "right" way is in the lib, the "faster" way is in the config/initializers, both works.

Answer (score 0):

These sorts of things generally go in the `RAILS_ROOT/lib` directory. Everything in that directory is automatically loaded when Rails boots up, although N.B., unlike files in the `app` directory, these libraries don't get re-evaluated on every request, even in development mode, so if you're going to be testing changes on the fly, you're best of unit-testing your libraries on their own and waiting until they're polished before putting the final version in your `lib`.

[The Rails Guides](http://ryanbigg.com/guides/initialization.html#require-rails-paths) describe the actual order the files are loaded in, although you're perfectly free to defy the order and "jump" the gun, `require`ing a file earlier on.

Answer (score 0):

You can place that in `lib/`. Then, edit `config/application.rb` so lib is autoloaded:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: Thanks I added it to my /lib folder but I get the error still "undefined method `midsub' for #<String:0x105c2a280>
"